# Bed and Cot : Difference and usage

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I had a notion that cot is the wooden (Steel) frame where the bed lies.

But recenlty I came to know it isn't. Cot is for a baby? And bed is the whole thing that we sleep. Correct me if I am wrong. So what can you call the bed frame alone? Again a bed?

Comment: A cot is a no-frills, probably cheap, probably uncomfortable bed. For example, if you book a hotel room with 2 beds but a 3rd person shows up and wants to sleep there, you can ask the front desk for "a cot", and the maintenance guy will show up to your room with a small, folding bed that the unfortunate guest has to sleep in.  The bedframe is simply the bedframe. I've never heard of a bedframe referred to as a cot.

Comment: Maybe i heard it wrong from someone.

Comment: In the UK the most common usage of cot is a bed with high sides for a baby, i.e. what in North America is often called a crib. It can also mean a narrow, (often) low bed, such as a camp bed.

Comment: [3 hots and a cot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/three_hots_and_a_cot) is a popular rhyming expression in the US. You don't use it for a normal bed. It is mainly used for beds in a prison and a shelter in addtion to what Dan mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

I think  you are looking for [bedstead](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bed+frame):

> - The frame supporting a bed.

(AHD)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What is AHD?

Comment: Yes this is what i asked for.

Comment: American Heritage Dictionary

Comment: You nailed it!!!